# How does one draw and notate a pressure gradient vector arrow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology

How does one draw and notate a pressure gradient vector arrow?

In the figure below I drew two options that came to mind: Arrow (1) and associated notation Eqn (1), and Arrow (2) and associated notation Eqn (2).

I'm not sure if one or both are correct or incorrect.  I would like to know which is/are the the correct (or incorrect) and I would like to get the argument(s) for how to correctly draw and notate a pressure gradient vector arrow (the how and why).

The associated fluid velocity vector $\vec v$ is directed along the $+x_1$ coordiante direction, and is considered a positive value through the relation:
$$\vec v=-\mathbf{K}\nabla p$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I don't understand fully your question, but "gradient of pressure" is defined by equation (1) and thus directed as the arrow going from blue to red. This is why in Navier-Stokes equation pressure term is $-\nabla P$, which manfests the fact that pressure gradient causes transport of fluid in the opposite direction to its gradient.

Equation (2) is "minus gradient of pressure".

Comment: So you are saying use Eqn(1) and the Arrow (2)? "Gradient" Wiki says that, "The gradient can be interpreted as the "direction and rate of fastest increase". If at a point p, the gradient of a function of several variables is not the zero vector, the direction of the gradient is the direction of fastest increase of the function at p, and its magnitude is the rate of increase in that direction." Arrow (2) is showing the direction of fastest _decrease_. Your thoughts?

Comment: Isn't high pressure red and low pressure is blue.  So the pressure gradient vector points from blue to red, line 1?

Comment: @ChetMiller that's correct.

Comment: yes, that was typo, from blue to red